# Best Practises for (error-) logging

Tags: javascript, php, error-handling, error-logging

So I'm trying to create logging for my web-app. It's written in HTML/CSS/JS for the frontend and PHP for the backend, using a MariaDB database. I'm trying to create logging for error/warnings etc in all my code. Meaning, not only for the PHP code, also JS (and maybe in the future even more languages).
Most of the handling in both PHP and JS is already done, and the JS errors are sent to the server via AJAX. Now the thing I'm stuck on is, what's the best way to save these errors to the database.

Right now I have 1 table in the database for error, which looks like this:

```
id         BIGINT  (10)  -- Primary Key
message    TEXT          -- The error message
type       VARCHAR (255) -- warning/error/notice/deprication etc...
origin     VARCHAR (255) -- JS/PHP etc...
account_id BIGINT  (10)  -- Foreign Key to an account table

c_dt DATETIME            -- Creation datetime
u_dt DATETIME            -- Update datetime
d_dt DATETIME            -- Delete datetime (implementation of soft delete)
```

NOTE: This is not the same as an audit log, which is implemented in a different table.

To clarify; `message` is just a single formatted string, that is created from the thrown event. A few real examples of this string are:

- phpHandler caught the following event: 2: mysqli::real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given. File: \path\to\the\databaseManager.php, Line: 206.
- ReferenceError: myfunc is not defined. File: myFile.js Line: 22 Column: 70
- phpHandler caught the following event: 8: Undefined index: routine. File: \path\to\the\Entrance.php, Line: 7.

However, I cannot (easily) grab, for example, the line number from the string. Or group by filename and see which files cause the most trouble. Adding columns like filename or line number would, of course, fix this. But not all languages give out the same information when an error occurs. For example, the error object in JS has a column number, filename, line number, browser name etc... but PHP has way fewer information on all this. And if I want to implement more (backend) languages in the future, there will only be more differences in information.

So my question is, what are the best practices for saving errors to the database? every (group of *similar*) language its own table with respective information? 1 Table with a lot of columns? Only save the basics, like file/line number severity?

Also, what could be some Pros and Cons of above-mentioned solutions that I may have overlooked?

Comment: Take a look at [help/on-topic]

Comment: looks to me like some kind of **[yagni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)** ... who will use (read) this table, in what use case.  Other options are available, try not to roll your own.

Comment: I'd look through Sentry's PHP client, which grabs adjacent source and stack locals: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-php.
For JS, you probably want to consider how different browsers have subtly different stack traces. Sentry's JS client may also help here https://github.com/getsentry/raven-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use a JSON type field in your database.
[For more information about JSON type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)

You may log detailed information about your warnings, errors etc. Just be careful to store queryable fields as a field in your table.

Comment: Nice suggestion! Please correct me if I'm wrong, but implementation would be as follows?: When an error occurs, I store the relevant info (defined by where/what language it occurred) in a JSON and store that JSON + the type to the DB. Then to retrieve I get the JSON from DB and determined by the type, I format it in a certain way.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, you may deserialize its contents. But as you see you can search in Json contents to if you need. (SELECT JSON_SET('"x"', '$[0]', 'a');). If you really need to search in JSON. By the way for the logging use archive type database engine.

Answer (score 0):

it is not the good way to create many columns for each field in your database,
if logging errors in specific files will not satisfy you (in almost most cases is the best way) or if you want to save it in a database in case of presentation or simplicity you should save the data in portable format ,
if you dont wanna query againt that data you can encode the whole message in json (TEXT MESSAGE) (if you have any additional data you can serialize that ). for example

```
/**
 * @param $exception
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function failed(Exception $exception)
{
    YOUR_MODEL::save(
        [
            'error' => json_encode([
                "file" => $exception->getFile(),
                "line" => $exception->getLine(),
                "message" => $exception->getMessage()
            ])
        ]);

    throw $exception;
}
```